# Start UIGestureRecognizer from Code

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

i got a UIViewSubclass Ball with a UIPanGestureRecognizer.
If i drag the Ball above a other UIView (in UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) the complete Superview gets cleared including the Ball. After that the Ball will be recreated.

My problem is that, with removing the ball naturally the UIGestureRecognizer ends recognizing.

How i can tell the gestureRecognizer of the new Ball to start recognize in code, cause my finger is still on the screen?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you clearing the superview including the ball? Are you removing it? If yes, then you could try making the ball invisible instead of removing it, by setting its alpha to 0.

Comment: my problem is that there are more than one balls and on dragging the ball of the view i load other balls. So my UIView could explode of invisible subviews. 
Have done something simular, now i check if the gesturerecognizer is in state changed and skip the object remove. But its anymore interesting for me if its possible to restart the gesturerecognizer from code

Comment: I am trying to understand the problem. When do you recreate the ball?

Comment: in that new case no more, i just remove all other balls.   
But in the source problem the user draged the ball over the uiview -> removed all balls and recreated the fingerball and all other balls